# Get and display specific values related to a post id and a meta_key

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Hello I tried this method but it's not working
there is more than a value related to the meta_key

```
<?php 

$post_meta_key = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_langue', true );
if( count($post_meta_key) > 0 ){ #check if we got any results
 foreach ($post_meta_key as $post_meta_key){ ?>
    •&nbsp<? echo $meta->meta_value . "<br />";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) doc. - having third parameter as true ( default ) have sense only if you have 1 meta named "_langue" attached to one post.

In other cases set `false` as third parameter and it will be returned as array ( except you save array  )

So you can try replace it with

```
<?php 
$langue = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_langue', true ); // value or empty string
// $langue_array = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_langue' ); // array([0] => "value");

if( empty($langue) ) 
    echo "no value set"
else echo $langue;
?>
```

Or remove third parameter and replace `$meta->meta_value` with `$meta` - it does not return an object

Comment: I don't know how to save an array and display it that's my problem

Comment: @NebilChâaba When you try to save array as meta value, it will be automatically seialized into string and unseralized on get_post_meta